# I want to insert data into MySQL database with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, beautifulsoup

I am doing web scraping and I want to store the information in the database. I have the connection with the database in the 'settings' file like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 'port'
    }
}
```

The web scraping I have it in another file like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.somepage.com"
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

find_by_class = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"body"}).find_all('p')
```

I want to store what is in find_by_class in the database.

Also I have created the models.

```
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried to connect your code snippet with your model! So far I see no relation between the two.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried to make an `from models import SomeModel` in the scraping file and then tried this `description = find_by_class` . But of course it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have done migrations in database (if not then inside your project's root folder, run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`).

Now you need to use the following snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from .models import SomeModel

url = "https://www.somepage.com"
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
find_by_class = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"body"}).find_all('p') 
for each in find_by_class:
    SomeModel.objects.create(description=each.text)
```

Comment: Yes I did migrations and create 0001_initial file.

Comment: This appear in the output: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models' "

Comment: The file containing scrapping code and models should be in same django app folder. else import model from someapp like `from appname.models import SomeModel`

Comment: Now I get this: 'ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'. Try to create a new project to verify and the same happens.

Comment: Remove the '.' from models and get this:  `ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the 
environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`